# Jupyter: why can't I import a `.py` file with a method containing a shell command?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

This works from my notebook (python 3):

```
from google.colab import auth
def google_cloud_auth(project_id):
  auth.authenticate_user()
  !gcloud config set project {project_id}
  return project_id

project_id = "my-project"
google_cloud_auth(project_id)
# Updated property [core/project].
```

This does NOT:

```
import colab_utils

project_id = "my-project"
colab_utils.google_cloud_auth(project_id)
# ERROR:
  File "/content/colab_utils.py", line 14
    !gcloud config set project {project_id}
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's the same method in `colab_utils.py`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not valid python. You should consider changing that line into os.popen call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands are not supposed to work in vanilla Python.

Exclamation marks (and many other cell magic features) are a specific feature of Jupyter/IPython shell. They are handled by the shell before command exectution and never passed to actual Python.

Comment: is there a workaround? I just need to organize some frequently used util functions

Comment: @michael I guess something like `os.system("gcloud config set project %s" % project_id)` might be sufficient

Comment: I just tried but I get the return code instead of `stdout`. I ended up using `subprocess`